# Adding to database SQlite Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I was getting an error while entering values in a database:

```
values = []
for dictionary in dictionaries:
        for element in keys:
            if element in cols:
                curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,\
                              ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', dictionary[element])
                #values.append(dictionary[element])
            else:
                curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,\
                              ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 'NA')
                #values.append('NA')

        #curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', tuple(values))


Error: OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Basically, I'm traversing through each dictionary accessing certain values and trying to input them into database. I check whether the "key" for dictionary is inside another list, if it is, then add some value to the database, otherwise add a "NA".

I have provided how I defined the table in the database:

```
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE Root_table(\
                Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'a' TEXT, 'b' TEXT,\
                'c' TEXT, 'd' TEXT, 'e' TEXT, 'f' TEXT, 'g' TEXT, 'h' TEXT,\
                'i' TEXT, 'j' TEXT,'k' TEXT, 'l' TEXT, 'm' TEXT, 'n' TEXT,\
                'o' TEXT, 'p' TEXT, 'q' TEXT, 'r' TEXT, 's' TEXT, 't' TEXT,\
                'u' TEXT, 'v' TEXT, 'w' TEXT, 'x' TEXT, 'y' TEXT, 'z' TEXT)")
```

Total number of question marks `?` in `curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', dictionary[element])` is 25, while there are 26 columns in the table (the first one is the ID element, which should autoincrement as per number of rows).

Comment: You could use multiline string literals `"""multiple lines"""` or use implicit string literal concatenation: `("one line" ... "another")` instead of `\\` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax isn't correct. You need to add `values` to your query, and because you're not providing data for all columns, you need to specify which:

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.execute("create table mytable (_id integer primary key, a, b)")
c.execute("insert into mytable (a,b) values  (?, ?)", (2,3))
c.execute('select * from mytable').fetchall()
# [(1,2,3)]
```

Comment: If I stored the entries in value and executed this: `curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', tuple(values))`, I still get an error (even though this is providing all the data for every column).

Comment: Try `curs.execute('INSERT INTO Root_table (`<all_your_fieldnames_except_for_id, comma separated>`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', tuple(values))`

Comment: I'm getting an error `25 values for 26 columns` with the method described ^. What's weird is that I execute a `print len(values)` right before `curs.execute(...)` and I see 26.

Comment: The size of `value` is 26 and `"field name except the id"` is 26.